# Sorting a list based on another list or a different size

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

Consider the following lists:

```
List<string> ordered = new List<string> (new string [] { "one", "two", "three", ... });
List<string> sequence1 = new List<string> (new string [] { "two", "three", "ten", ... });
```

The list `[ordered]` is a superset with all possible values.

The list `[sequence1]` is a randomly-ordered subset of the `[ordered]` list. It may contain some or all of the super set's elements.

I currently have a long-winded function that sorts `[sequence1]` based on `[ordered]` and was wondering if a simpler Linq way to do it. The current method iterates the super-set using a for loop and tries to find the value in the subset and moves it to its relevant position.

The number of items in the list will never be more than a few dozen and the sorting operation will sparingly be called so efficiency is not key here.

Comment: how do you sort them now? could you show the code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ordering by the index should work:

```
var result = sequence1.OrderBy(ordered.IndexOf);
```

However, if there might be items that are not in `ordered`, you'll need to do some extra processing:

```
var result = from n in sequence1
             let i = ordered.IndexOf(n)
             orderby i == -1 ? ordered.Count : i
             select n
```

Comment: That is pretty damn clever. It might be worth checking if the result is `-1` though.

Comment: Wow! I love this one. Gotta test it out.

Comment: @GregRos Added an alternative option if there is a chance that some items might not be in ordered.

Comment: @VijayaKrishnaParuchuri I thought you could end with an orderby. Nvm, fixed now.

Comment: Since `ordered` will always be a supers set, `subset.OrderBy(ordered.IndexOf)` works fine and is clever indeed.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. When I use this method, I got `The incoming request has too many parameters` error, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Use the index as sort criteria, this is without LINQ:

```
sequence1.Sort
(
    (x, y) =>
    {
        return ordered.IndexOf(x).CompareTo(ordered.IndexOf(y));
    }
);
```

---

You could take from `ordered` only those that exists in `sequence1`:

```
from x in ordered where sequence1.Contains(x) select x
```

Though, this approach is less efficient.

---

These approaches has ben tested on LINQPad.

Comment: Thanks. I like the query syntax version.